# How to implement floating point using 16 bit words

Tags: math, floating-point, 16-bit

How would I implement floating point operations if I only have memory locations that are 16 bits wide?

I am trying to implement IEEE-754 32-bit single precision floating point.

Thank you

Comment: You need to specify the required range and precision before anyone can answer this

Comment: From your comments to the answers it appears as though you want larger values than fit into a single 16-bit word. In that case, what do you need? Normally, one does not implement floating points operations yourself but use built-in types like float or double. If you plan to write something yourself, maybe you could do something like a fixed-point solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring out that there is no easy way to to this. I had to create my own software library for all of the functions in assembly.
If anybody has questions regarding how to do this, I implemented add,subtract,multiply,square root, divide, cosine, and sine.

Comment: I can share the algorithms. What are you interested in?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [16bit version of IEEE754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: I understand, but i need a larger range.  I am subtract numbers like 4385.661621938 - 50

Comment: @starbox: it's probably not going to work - why not just use pairs of 16 bit locations to give you 32 bit IEEE-754 floats ?

Comment: k i could do that, but how do i handle the arithmetic?

Comment: @starbox: pretty much the same way as in math class.

Comment: @starbox, 4385.661621938 cannot be represented with 16 bits: it's `1000100100001.101010010110000000001110001010` in binary...

Comment: @MartinBeckett, I was looking for a way to implement 32-bit IEEE754. Thank you for your answer though.